# Quick fix? Or major problem? Please help

Tags: battery, sparkplugs, head-gasket, cylinder-head

Help, 02 honda civic lx coupe cranks but will not start. I bought the car less then 3 months ago put used rebuild trans in it seemd fine then what seemed to be running hot but with no warning signs so i bought new temp gauge still same problem would lose all acceleration at normal speeds even while in cruise control. Been refilling everyday with water/anti and would stil sputter and just run rugged when in idle as well as when you 1sr try turning car over. Wouldnt catch 1st time cranking or sputter back off. I t has a brand new radiator iv checked the fuel pump and its good. I literally spent almost 2,000$ already on this lx. Please tell me if theres a quick fix solution to this issue im having here.

Comment: Is there coolant in the oil?

Comment: No oil looks like what oil is supposed to like. Also was thinking it could be cutoff relay switch